# What is the ideal corePoolSize for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

In my Java web application, I am using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to periodically check the database connection status. This is for every authenticated user (per authentication).

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(0);

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          //check the status of the database connection, and log the result
     }
};

        
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

However, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor consumes 100% CPU when corePoolSize = 0. Setting corePoolSize = 1, resolves the issue.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

In production we would have hundreds of users. **My question is, in this case, what would be the ideal value for corePoolSize?**

Answer (score 1):

> periodically check the database connection status

Is this polling as a health check or are you rolling your own DB connection pool?

> However, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor consumes 100% CPU when corePoolSize = 0. Setting corePoolSize = 1, resolves the issue.

How did you determine this? You can check the threads view in VisualVM, but even though all these threads were running, the JVM never went past 3% CPU use. It's worth noting the thread pool thread is mostly parked.

[image]

> In production we would have hundreds of users. My question is, in this case, what would be the ideal value for corePoolSize?

How many thread pools are you spinning up? One per authentication is pretty inefficient. Same with connections. Like I mentioned before, you usually want to pool them. How are you keeping connections open across the lifecycle of an "authentication?" Are you storing connections in an `HttpSession`, i.e. `request.getSession()`?  This is a bad idea because of how much overhead is associated with a connection and how easy it is to have cleanup issues.

Do you have a shared pool and you're not stopping old tasks? That could pin CPU use.

All that said, the general rule for a thread pool is threads=qps*latency, so if you check the connection every 10s, checking the connection takes 1s, and you have 60 connections, you need 6 threads + headroom. Reading your sample, that doesn't seem to be your problem. It sounds like you're spinning up way too many thread pools and possibly leaking them.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes, this is a type of health check using  java.​sql.​Connection.isValid(0) method.

I determined the CPU usage using htop command of Linux.

I am creating one thread-pool per authentication. However, I am stopping the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor (using shutdown method) when the user logs out or closes the browser window.

I am keeping the connections open across the lifecycle of an authentication by calling the java.​sql.​Connection.isValid(0) method periodically (say every 10 minutes).

Comment: How about if I use a static variable for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor so that a single instance of it gets shared among the users/authentication? Would that be more efficient?

Comment: "when the user logs out or closes the browser window." Those hooks aren't great. People leave windows open and never log out all the time, and callback hooks don't always fire. Especially if it's just a SQL connection, you're much better off pooling them.